# Subgroup of Galois group of polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be the splitting field of $x^5-3 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

We can see $K = \mathbb{Q}(3^{1/5}, \zeta_5)$ where $\zeta_5 = e^{2 \pi i/5}$, and $[K: \mathbb{Q}] = 20$. It's easy to see $\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)\subseteq K$.

Let $H= \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$). Does $H$ have to be abelian?

**Edit:**
The Galois group of the big extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is the group generated by $\sigma$ (order 5 element) and $\tau$ (order 4 element) defined by
$\sigma: 3^{1/5} \mapsto 3^{1/5} \zeta_5$ and $\tau: \zeta_5 \mapsto \zeta_5^2$.

I don't know what this group is, but it's definitely not abelian since if it's abelian the extension $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/5})/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois.

Comment: You should be able to find the group of $K$ over $\bf Q$, and then find $H$ as a subgroup of that group.

Comment: @colge Have you computed the Galois group of the big extension
?

Comment: @BenjaLim I have tried this (see my edit of the quesion) but I didn't get exact representation of this group.

Comment: @colge It's the Frobenius group $F_{20}$.

Comment: You should be able to find a relation involving $\sigma$ and $\tau$, decide whether there are any elements of order 10, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what's left to do here, since you've asked whether $H$ has to be abelian and then you've determined that it isn't. You might want to show that $\sigma$ and $\tau^2$ are in $H$, but $\tau$ isn't. Do you know that there is a simple theorem that completely classifies the groups of order $2p$ for prime $p$?

Comment: Can someone please explain why $H$ is abelian imply $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/5})/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois ?

Answer (score 1):

The Galois group is of order 20, generated by $x$ of order 5 any $y$ of order 4, where $yxy^{-1}=x^{3}$. Its the Frobenius group of order 20. The subgroup of order 10 is generated by $x$ and $y^2$. It is a dihedral group.

Comment: If the group is abelian, how do you explain the fact that $\mathbb{Q}[3^{1/5}]/\mathbb{Q}$ is not an abelian extension, as the OP mentionned?

Comment: I think you've got the dicyclic group of order 20; the Frobenius group has relation $yxy^{-1}=x^3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson-you are right. So the subgroup of order 10 is dihedral, not abelian.